# Querying two different post types with the same taxonomony

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a two custom post types "venues" and "events".. How do i query "venues" then display all the "events" that have the same taxonomy values.

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'venue-name';
$param_type = 'venue-name';
$tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID , $taxonomy, $tax_args);
if ($tags) {
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'venues',
              "$param_type" => $tag->slug,
              'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
              'showposts'=> 1,    
          );
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test the following code but it should help you in the right direction.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('venues', 'events'),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $tags,
        )
    )
);
```